Why does BasicDataSource object reinitialisation cause 'data source is closed' error?
I have a BasicDataSource bean called dataSource and this is used to establish JDBC connection.
databaseSql = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
databaseCall= new SimplejdbcCall(dataSource);

During runtime I reinitialised (destroyed and created again) this singleton bean and re-established JDBC connection by calling the above code.
I set the maxIdle and minIdle to be 0, to prevent any idle connection causing an error. However, when I do it, I get 'data source is closed' error. Why does it happen and how can I create a new JDBC connection?

Just get a new connection, why are you re-creating the datasource? Also re-creating a singleton is a bad idea as you don't know where it is being used, next to that don't recreate the JdbcTemplate as that is quite heavy to create just create once and re-use. What you are doing basically defeats the purpose of singletons and what Spring Boot gives you from auto configuration.

@M.Deinum I'm trying to update the password of dataSource.

Update and restart the application, or add Spring Cloud config and use @RefreshScope for the datasource to refresh it after a password change. Don't try to recreate a singleton that will only lead to problems.

Sounds to me like your code is still referencing the old data source that you destroyed and replaced with a different one, but without a [mre] that is just a guess.

As an aside, trying to prevent idle connections makes zero sense and reduces the effectiveness and efficiency of the connection pool.
